# CredentialManager: The incoming request cannot be validated

Tags: android, ngrok, fido, credential-manager

Cross-posting from https://github.com/android/identity-samples/issues/51

I am also trying to implement FIDO2 on Android. Using the CredentialManager sample app, when I click on "Sign Up with passkey", I get `createPasskey failed with exception: The incoming request cannot be validated`.

I am using ngrok to host my localhost, and I can see my assetlinks file, so I am not sure why it can't be validated.

I read this related [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76512753/android-fido-security-err-the-incoming-request-cannot-be-validated), and I added the asset_statements to my AndroidManifest, but I ended up deleting it because it didn't work and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/passkeys#add-support-dal) says this step is not required if you are only using passkeys.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the assets-link json file can not be reached by the Android OS.
In my case I found out the assetlinks.json that was stored on my test domain which it's ssl https certificate was expired:

```
 x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

Fixed that and the error solved.

Answer (score 0):

After spending two days finally i got the answer of your question.

Step 1: First add your release SHA256 key with your package name into assetlinks.json file and upload it your rp (realing party website) /.well-known path

Step 2: Change your build varint to release build.

Step 3: Most important step is to add build flavour inside signInConfig block in build.gradle file like this

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        
    }
    release {
        storeFile file('../my_keystore.keystore')
        storePassword 'password'
        keyAlias 'password'
        keyPassword 'password'
    }
}
```

step 4 : Inside buildTypes block asscess your release file flavour

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

Now you are good to go. this steps will work on both Fido2 and CredentialManager api android